# How to exclude <ul> element during jquery keyup live search?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript/jquery and am trying to figure out how to exclude/filter out ul class="dropdown-menu" under ul id="#modulelist". I still want to be able to search through the li elements not under ul class="dropdown-menu". Below is a snippet of my PHP and jquery codes.

```
<ul class="to_do" id = "modulelist">
                       <?php
                       foreach($course_titles_not_completed as $course_title){
                           echo '<li class="dropdown">';
                           echo '<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a>';
                           echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">';

                        if(!empty($prereq_course_titles)){
                        foreach($prereq_course_titles as $prereq_course_title){
                            echo '<li><a href="#">';
                            echo $prereq_course_title;
                            echo '</a></li>';
                        }
                        }
                        else{
                            echo '<li><a href="#">';
                            echo 'No prerequisites';
                            echo '</a></li>';
                        }

                           echo '</ul>';
                           echo '<input type="checkbox" class="flat">';
                           echo $course_title;
                           echo '</li>';
                       }
                       ?>
                    </ul>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
          var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          $("#modulelist li").each(function(){
              var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
              if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                  $(this).hide();
              }else{
                  $(this).show();
              }
          });
      });
  });
  </script>
```

I can't seem to not include the ul class = "dropdown-menu" and it's children li elements in the search. I do not want to remove the ul and li elements as a solution as I still need them to appear if nothing is entered in the search bar.

Please do help me and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `>` selector the select the first level `li` under `#modulelist`

```js
$("#modulelist > li").each((i, e) => {
  console.log(e.tagName, e.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="to_do" id="modulelist">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">1</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>1.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">2</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li>2.1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```